# Is possible to refactor this function?

Tags: jquery

I have an article with some popups (hotspot) on this. I need to click on its for adding a visible class. On this article I have to render visible only one hotspot.

```
function calloutHandler("article") {
  var $hotspotIcon = $slot.find('.hotspot-icon');

  $hotspotIcon.each(function(index, el) {
    var dataVal = $(this).attr('data-val'),
      $hotspotCallout = $slot.find('[data-val=' + dataVal + '].hotspot');

    $(el).on("click", function() {
      var doesvisible = $hotspotCallout.hasClass("visible");

      $slot.find('.item.hotspot').removeClass("visible");
      doesvisible ? null : $hotspotCallout.addClass("visible");
    });
  });
}

<article>
<div class="hotspot-icon" data-val="123"></div>
<div class="item hotspot" data-val="123"></div>
</article>
```

I would to refactor this function, I can't find other solutions. Do you've suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by refactoring? What is in your mind?

Comment: @Andrew Using a ternary to add a class seems like really bad practice.

Comment: `$slot.find('.hotspot-icon[data-val='+dataVal+']');` but what is `.hotspot` An attribute? Then jQuery will need `.attr("hotspot")` nah, the code does not make any sense. Please post the HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: I changed the function and I added html code

Comment: what is `$slot` ?

Comment: @AshleyBrown Looks like they typoed it but "article" is now in place of $slot so $slot is probably an article.

Comment: @Andrew You need to expand on what your end goal is. You are doing some strange selections  that make it look like you are ommiting HTML. Otherwise you could just do `$(el).click(() => $hotspotCallout.toggleClass("visible"));`

Comment: @Marie I have an article with some popups (hotspot) on this. I need to click on its for adding a visible class. On this article I have to render visible only one hotspot.

Comment: @Andrew I may have worded my question poorly. Often when asking for programming help people like to ask for help with a solution when really a MUCH better solution may exist if they shared their root problem ([XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/326778)). When asking for help it is best to describe what your front end looks like and what you would like to do AND give an example of what you have tried. In this case you should post a full example of HTML and describe what you want to happen. E.g. "When you click on the red box the green box disappears" or something similar.